# past perfect for an event which is still true

Tags: past-tense

. The Cambrian _____ an important moment in the history of life on earth and a time of radical evolutionary experimentation when many animals first_____ in the fossil record.

the answer is had been, appeared. Why had been because it is still true why not present is

https://www.englishtestsonline.com/mixed-tenses-advanced-level-test-quiz-online-exercise-with-answers-2/

Comment: Whoever wrote that quiz does not speak English well. For example, the sentence *"When he called her as a cheater, she complained him to the headmaster"* is ungrammatical, not because of the tenses but because it should be *"called her a cheater"* and *"complained about him."* Disregard the answer they give; *"was"* is a much better word to fill in the blank.

Answer (score 1):

It would most likely be "The Cambrian was..."

The second missing word must be "appeared" as it describes a particular event in the past.

The first is describing a past time. For that simple past can be used.

> 2012 was a great year!

If you want to describe a time period that continues until now, use the present perfect

> 2018 has been a great year so far!

If you want to describe a past time period up to a certain point you can use past perfect

> 2013 had been a great year, until October when I got sick and lost my job.

The test quote may have been extracted from longer context that justifies the past perfect.

> The Cambrian had been an important moment... but was followed by the Ordovician when many of these new forms went extinct.

Answer (score 0):

Appearing in the sense of "arriving" is not a continuous thing; you appear instantaneously, and then you are just there, not appearing any more.  You would say "Jane appeared at the party an hour ago", even if she is still there and never left.

However, as a native speaker who is also a biologist, I'd say the sentence makes just as much sense all in the present tense, I think because you are describing what the evidence, in the present, demonstrates.

A google search of "appear in the fossil record" turns up almost as many hits as "appeared in the fossil record".